# How to distinguish easily different soldier of ww2?

Tags: warfare

Not sure if it's on topic.
I and some friends are doing a short movie, just for fun. The theme is ww2, and we have some soldier costumes, but they will be the same for all soldiers, so German, soviet and British soldiers will all look the same.

How can I make that we distinguish soldiers easily on each scene?

One thing could be name like Hans, but this seems odd, as in normal dialogue, you don't usually call someone by his name

Comment: All I can think off is changing how they exactly wear their uniforms. For example the British would wear it by-the-book while soviet would wear it partially undone, helmet eschew (unless its supposed to be winter) and with some added dirty bandages or something. Perhaps have a coloured hankerchied sticking out of a breastpocket, bound around a head, sleeve or weapon to colour-code each faction.

Comment: Can your friends make/procure some insignia?

Comment: Welcome to the site NotANazi, please take the [tour] and read up in our help centre about how we work: [ask] You'll see in [help/on-topic] that your question is not on topic, but you can [edit] it to make it so.

Comment: I'm not sure this is a *worldbuilding* question. It's about depicting them in a story, not making your own story world where this depiction will take place in.

Comment: VTC OT:NAW.  However, if you have enough costumes, clothing dyes are cheap (khaki=british, grey=german, etc).  If not, you're stuck with insignia.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In addition to Henry's answer, I would say: music.

### WW2 was just a big musical comedy, with quite realistic fights.

Joke aside, music played an important role in WW2. It was the first total war with mass distributed music, and each side have his own recognizable style.

Just play some famous music, a red army choir music will give a huge hint on wich side a soldier is

Comment: This approach worked perfectly for *Girls und Panzer*, an anime where all characters are Japanese, but they fight in historical WW2 vehicles. The teams are based on different nations, and whenever tanks of a specific team are shown, a historical music of that nation is heard in the background. This is the music where all the teams are introduced before the final battle: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BRyIEnkk86Q Too bad it's audio-only, but you can identify the characteristic marches of Germany, USA, Soviet Union, United Kingdom, Italy, Finland and Japan.

Answer (score 8):

**Moustaches.**
Cheap, fun, and country specific!

French males generally have twirly, skinny waxed mustaches.

[image: French stache]

UK soldiers have furry, elaborate moustaches; larger yet if you are Scottish.

[image]

Of course WW2 Germans would all have prim little Hitlery mustaches.

[image: adolf]
[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adolf_Galland)

Americans of the era generally wore thin Cab Calloway type jazz mustaches.
[image]

Answer (score 7):

Since it is all for fun, historical accuracy is not important.  Find some small British Russian, and Nazi flags and cut them into the breast pockets on your uniform shirts.  Use Velcro tape to temporarily affix the flags to the shirts, changing them out between scenes.  If you can find some slightly larger flags, you could do the same thing to the backs of the shirts so that soldier's can be recognized from behind as well.

In the place of flags, you could use ethnic stereotypes such as fur collars, cuffs and fake mustaches for the Russians.   Also work a lot of salutes into the script as an easy German identifier tool.

Also, bad accents can't hurt.